# How to use HSCAN command in Redis?

Tags: redis, hiredis

I want to use Redis's HSCAN command in my assignment but I have no idea how it works. Redis's official page (http://redis.io/commands/hscan) for this command gives me blank page.

I am getting continuous input data and saving them instantaneously in multiple hashes in Redis and I would like to iterate through all of them at later point of time.

I'm using following command to save my data

```
HMSET myhash ordertype "neworder" order_ts "1234" act_type "order_ack" ack_ts "1240"
HMSET myhash2 ordertype "neworder" order_ts "2234" act_type "order_ack" ack_ts "2240"
```

Can anyone give me some examples of how to use HSCAN?

In my case I would like to get following output 
1) myhash 
2) myhash2 
3) myhash3 
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 17):

**Commands**

Start a full hash scan with:

`HSCAN myhash 0`

Start a hash scan with fields matching a pattern with:

`HSCAN myhash 0 MATCH order_*`

Start a hash scan with fields matching a pattern and forcing the scan command to do more scanning with:

`HSCAN myhash 0 MATCH order_* COUNT 1000`

**Note**

Don't forget that **MATCH** can return little to no element for each iteration, as explained in the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/scan):

> It is important to note that the MATCH filter is applied after
>   elements are retrieved from the collection, just before returning data
>   to the client. This means that if the pattern matches very little
>   elements inside the collection, SCAN will likely return no elements in
>   most iterations.

And that's why you can use `COUNT` to force more scanning for each iteration.

**[Update]** As [Didier Spezia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114486/didier-spezia) specified, you'll need Redis 2.8+ to use the *SCAN commands.

Comment: And please note you need Redis 2.8 to get scanning capabilities. Stable Redis is still 2.6.

Comment: I think he is confused. what he want is the hash keys as output while HSCAN will scan the values of scan.

Comment: Is it possible to use match in a complex data type/Object?

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned by you. you need to get the output of hash keys

```
myhash
myhash2
myhash3
```

HSCAN is not for this purpose. HSCAN is to scan the fields of a particular HASH. so you can scan the fields of myhash or myhash2. But if you want to find the keys on the basis of patterns you have two options.

Create a SET with the HASH keys

```
SADD hashkeys "myhash" "myhash1" "myhash2"

SMEMBERS hashkeys
    1) "myhash"
    2) "myhash2"
    3) "myhash1"

If you are using 2.8 I would recommend you use sscan instead of smembers

sscan hashkeys 0 match my*
```

USE ONLY SCAN COMMAND

```
scan 0 MATCH myhash* count 1000
```

USE key matching (NOT RECOMMENDED AS it will block the redis server)

```
keys myhash*
```

So long story cut sort to fetch the keys you can use SMEMBERS, SSCAN or KEYS. Ofcourse best is SSCAN if you are using redis 2.8