# Get value set of a large map

Tags: redis

I have a large map, which maps skuIds (strings, e.g.: `AB-1` to "hola") to names; the skuIds are unique, but the names are not.

There are about 1 million skuIds mapped to about 1000 unique names. Now I need to get the unique name list for any subset of the skuId set.

I tried hashmap's `hmget`, but retrieving millions of records and looping through is not effiecient; then I tried using the Sorted sets, (kept the same score for same name), but then I needed the set of scores for a sorted set, which is not provided directly by redis.

We can do this by using a Lua script (taking about 10-15 seconds), but I am not sure about disadvantages of having Lua scripts in the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "but then I needed the set of scores for a sorted set, which is not provided directly by redis"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/HSCAN) for that. Also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910527/how-to-use-hscan-command-in-redis) about [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/HSCAN) usage.